# Sentry CaptureMessage without Flush

Tags: go, error-handling, sentry

Am I correct that in the Go project to send messages immediately, the Flush method must be used?
When I try sending messages without `Flush()` it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/getsentry/sentry-go#Client.Flush):

> Flush waits until the underlying Transport sends any buffered events
> to the Sentry server, blocking for at most the given timeout. It
> returns false if the timeout was reached. In that case, some events
> may not have been sent.
>
> Flush should be called before terminating the program to avoid
> unintentionally dropping events.
>
> Do not call Flush indiscriminately after every call to CaptureEvent,
> CaptureException or CaptureMessage. Instead, to have the SDK send
> events over the network synchronously, configure it to use the
> HTTPSyncTransport in the call to Init.

So while the problem you are asking about is a "valid" one in case you need to be sure a message is indeed sent to the server, the solution you are proposing (calling `Flush()` after a `CaptureMessage()`), is actively discouraged by the SDK authors. Instead, consider something like:

```
sentry.Init(sentry.ClientOptions{
    Transport: sentry.NewHTTPSyncTransport(),
    // ...
})
```

Comment: sentry.NewHTTPSyncTransport() doesn't implement required methods

Comment: With a small correction: 
Transport should be used instead of HTTPTransport

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @DmitryDyachkov, I have edited the answer appropriately. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I will accept Emile Pels answer with a correction that
`sentry.NewHTTPSyncTransport()`
should be assigned
to `Transport` instead of `HTTPTransport`

[image]